# int двоичное число место

Tags: c

где, как  храниться int?  не  значение переменной  а  эти три буквы int
Объясните чайнику
И вообще всякие int char

после того как int скомпилирован как он представляется в компьютере  заменены ли три символа int двоичной системой и комбинация 011010010110111001110111

Comment: чтобы ответить, что где и как хранится нужен ваш пример программы.

Comment: Эти три буквы не хранятся нигде, нет никакого смысла захламлять ими место в скомпилированной программе

Comment: Примерно... Вас отправляют в магазин. С напутствием "Купи хлеб." Где хранится этот хлеб? Не буханка, а эти четыре буквы? :) Вот примерно так же, только рассматривать надо не инструкцию в голове, а команды мышцам рук, когда вы выбираете буханку.